# Ways to delimit your text in VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, delimiter

I have a file with the following inputs

"SMEGOLD 1312",20131127,"C","11606233E","SMX","C",20131009,170028,"SMX","70207",0,1,4699,0,469.9,"USD",0,"",0,"",0,"",0,"",0,0,0,8062696,"",0,20131009,170028,"SYSTEM","25228","","166","121328200000223",785,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","",0,0,0,"",20131009,170028,"ADVMEE"

"SMEGOLD 1312",20131127,"C","11606233E","SMX","C",20131009,170030,"SMX","70207",0,1,4699,0,469.9,"USD",0,"",0,"",0,"",0,"",0,0,0,8062697,"",0,20131009,170031,"SYSTEM","25228","","167","121328200000223",786,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","",0,0,0,"",20131009,170028,"ADVMEE"

What i would like to achieve is to only obtain the first quote text of the line. Example "SMEGOLD 1312". Then i would like to append the first 3 characters and the last 4 characters of that extracted text to the back of line.

And move to the next line to carry on with the procedure till the end of the file.

Any advise will be a great help. I tried using the objRegEx.Pattern but to no avail

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern that cuts/groups the first field in toto (1), its first three (2) and its last four (3) characters, and all the rest (4). Then .Replace creatively:

```
>> s = Replace("'SMEGOLD 1312','whatever','ADVMEE'", "'", """")
>> WScript.Echo s
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "^((""[^""]{3})[^""]*?([^""]{4}""))(.*)"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(s,"$1$4,$2$3")
>>
"SMEGOLD 1312","whatever","ADVMEE"
"SMEGOLD 1312","whatever","ADVMEE","SME1312"
```

Comment: Also is there a way to count the number of spaces in a string or text?

Comment: @user3783939 - don't ask completely unrelated questions in comments. If the question is worth while, use the standard mechanism (after searching in vain for a solution).